# Trigger an async task on the server and return while the async task is running

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous

I am on a java platform using Spring on the server. I want to do the following

1. send a http request to the server that triggers an async task.
2. return a response from the server after triggering the async task without
   waiting for the async task to finish.

I am having difficulties with returning the response because the async task is blocking the main thread resulting in a timeout on the client while the async task is running.

Anybody know any articles with examples regarding this functionality or anybody got a small code snippet that can illustrate a good way of doing this.

Comment: "async thread is blocking the main thread" - pls be more specific. A thread can only block itself, I cannot understand how one thread blocks another one.

Comment: Seems to me that you dont know much about async yet and need some guidance to implement it correctly. Here is an example; you can try to understand it from: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async

Answer (score 0):

Your overall model approach is not necessarily incorrect.

However the following info:

> > the async task is blocking the main thread

implies that one of your assumptions is not holding: namely that the Server side were able to *quickly* return a status code.  That is crucial: if the Server hangs around doing heavy processing before returning an immediate return code - and thus relinquishing control back to the caller/client - then your client will hang as you have seen.

One of the following thus likely were needed:

- if you have control of the server side then update the server side behavior to return a code immediately instead of doing extra processing
- if not: then you need to change your client side to not even wait for the server to return *anything* before continuing.

The latter would mean you should change the client asuyncCode from

- client: launch request to server
- wait for server return code
- start async callback handler to await the *full* result from the server

to :

- client: start async callback handler to await *both* the initial result from the server *and* the *full* result from the server
- client main thread: continue other work so as not to hang the `main` loop

Answer (score 0):

solved this one by using spring @Async on the method i wanted to trigger and run async. So now the request triggers the async call and returns to server immediately while the async task is still running on the server